# Are these Hadoop setup/cleanup/run times reasonable?

Tags: hadoop

I've set up and am testing out a pseudo-distributed Hadoop cluster (with namenode, job tracker, and task tracker/data node all on the same machine). The box I'm running on has about 4 gigs memory, 2 cpus, 32-bit, and is running Red Hat Linux.

I ran the sample grep programs found in the tutorials with various file sizes and number of files. I've found that grep takes around 45 seconds for a 1 mb file, 60 seconds for a 100 mb file, and about 2 minutes for a 1 gig file.

I also created my own Map Reduce program which cuts out all the logic entirely; the map and reduce functions are empty. This sample program took 25 seconds to run.

I have tried moving the datanode to a second machine, as well as added in a second node, but I'm only seeing changes of a few seconds. Particularly, I have noticed that setup and clean up times are always about 3 seconds, no matter what input I give it. This seems to me like a really long time just for setup.

I know that these times will vary greatly depending on my hardware, configuration, inputs, etc. but I was just wondering if anyone can let me know if these are the times I should be expecting or if with major tuning and configuration I can cut it down considerably (for example, grep taking < 5 seconds total).

Answer (score 1):

So you have only 2 CPU's, Hadoop will spawn (in pseudo-distributed mode) many JVMs': One for the Namenode, 1 for the Datanode, 1 for the Tasktracker and 1 for the Jobtracker. For each file in your job path Hadoop sets up a mapper task and per task it will spawn a new JVM, too. So your two Cores are sharing 4-n applications. So your times are not unnormal...
 At least Hadoop won't be as fast for plain-text files as for sequence files. To get the REAL speedup you have to bring the text into serialized bytecode and let hadoop stream over it.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

- There is always a fixed time cost for every Hadoop job run to calculate the splits and launch the JVM's on each node to run the map and reduce jobs.
- You won't experience any real speedup over UNIX grep unless you start running on multiple nodes with lots of data.  With 100mb-1G files, a lot of the time will be spent setting up the jobs rather than doing actual grepping.  If you don't anticipate dealing with more than a gig or two of data, it probably isn't worth using Hadoop.